# what is the difference between AM_LDFLAGS and LDFLAGS

Tags: c, makefile, flags, automake

I want to know what is the difference between AM_LDFLAGS and LDFLAGS, as I've faced an error

```
error: AM_LDFLAGS must be set with '=' before using '+='
```

while I was using AM_LDFLAGS in a foreach loop 
my make file code is as shown below:

```
program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/bin/PR__bin

program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/lib/PR__lib

CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
```

Comment: The Gnu documentation says: "`AM_LDFLAGS` This is the variable the Makefile.am author can use to pass in additional linker flags. In some situations, this is not used, in preference to the per-executable (or per-library) `_LDFLAGS`". But it doesn't say *which* situations.

Comment: @WeatherVane was updating the same. you beat me by seconds. :-)

Comment: The difference is that `LDFLAGS` is probably set up or blanked out by Autoconf, but `AM_LDFLAGS` is an Automake-only variable, so if you don't explicitly give it any value, it's unset... hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that error is complaining about what it says it is complaining about (and I'm not at all sure why it would/should be) then I would think the solution would be as simple as just adding

```
AM_LDFLAGS =
```

as the line above the foreach loop that uses `+=`.

From section [`8.7 Variables used when building a program`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Variables.html#Program-Variables) of the GNU Automake manual:

> AM_LDFLAGS
>
> This is the variable the Makefile.am author can use to pass in additional linker flags. In some situations, this is not used, in preference to the per-executable (or per-library) _LDFLAGS.

Comment: Given that message, no, it would seem that it has no value by default (or that the default value is useless or include-able in your initial assignment somehow but I don't know). I still have no idea why the autotools would be complaining about this in the first place however.

Comment: yes, this answer solve the error of "error: AM_LDFLAGS must be set with '=' before using '+='"

Comment: but this will not overwrite the initial value if it has, as i mean the standard c library. ?

Comment: Don't set it and see what value `AM_LDFLAGS` has in the constructed makefiles. I'm betting it doesn't have any value.

Comment: @Sara `AM_LDFLAGS` should not have any "initial value" because its entire purpose is to be set by the author of the `Makefile.am` only. The whole point is that the author needs to specify the initial value.

Answer (score 5):

> _I want to know what is the difference between AM_LDFLAGS and LDFLAGS_

`LDFLAGS` is the variable inherited from Autoconf, `AM_LDFLAGS` is a variable defined by automake.

As per the automake [manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Variables.html),

> This is the variable the `Makefile.am` author can use to pass in additional linker flags. In some situations, this is not used, in preference to the per-executable (or per-library) `_LDFLAGS`.

However, reagrding the error, as per the information provided [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ode-users/yixmidOpyoQ), it looks like a problem on the usage of the variable. Automake expects that the variable must be set to *some* value before it can be *appended*.

The correct way to solve this would be same as the one mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658342/2173917) provided by Etan Reisner, simply *set* the `AM_LDFLAGS` explicitly before the loop, something like

```
AM_LDFLAGS =     // which "sets" the AM_LDFLAGS
```

and then do

```
AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
```

Comment: @juanchopanza well, because of the _bug_ OP might have thought otherwise. I thought this will help.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I'll upgrade automake and feed you back, but is there something wrong in my makefile, as I used AM_LDFLAGS with foreach loop 
and please another question should I use AM_CFLAGS instead of CFLAGS?

Comment: @Sara well, I'm also not very sure so better not to suggest anything wrong. You can update your question and maybe someone knowledgeable will help you out for sure. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh it didn't work with me as the automake version that i have is 1.14.1 ?

Comment: Oh, that error appears to be an error in that project that was fixed... presumably also in that project. Presumably by assigning to `AM_LDFLAGS` with `=` before using `+=` which should be as simple as adding a `AM_LDFLAGS=` line before the foreach.

Comment: That's not a bug in Automake at all; it's a bug in some random project that you found on Google. This doesn't answer the question, and I'm confused by how it got so many more votes than the correct answer.

Comment: @underscore_d Indeed, you're very correct. I never revisited the answer and now once you're pointed out, it looks like this is a wrong answer, let me edit to make it correct. and thanks again for leaving the comment, appreciate it.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Cool! :)