# Beginner in writing makefile; checking my Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, linker, flags, automake

I am trying to understand how to write my own makefile for small project, so I have a few questions 
my project consists of `src` directory that contains `main.c`, `file1.c`, `file2.c`, `header1.h`, and finally `header2.h` these files use some library from non standard library that I have created  and non standard header file, the library directory is located in `usr/lib/pr__lib` and the header directory is located in `usr/include/lib`
so I should create two `makefile.am` one will be located in `src` directory and the other one will be in root directory of the project the `makefile.am` of the `src` directory is as shown below:

```
 program_NAME := PRDSL

 bin_PROGRAMS = PRDSL_AutoProject

 program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/bin/PR__bin

 program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/lib/PR__lib

 CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

 program_LIBRARIES := \
         libprdependency \
         libprdynarray_pic \
         libprhistogram_pic \
         libprlistofarrays \
         libprlistofarrays_pic \
         libprmalloc \
         libvreo_wrapper_library 

 AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))

 AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

 PRDSL_AutoProject_SOURCES = \
         main.c \
         file1.c \
         file2.c

 depend :
      makedepend --$(CFLAGS) --$(PRDSL_AutoProject_SOURCES)

 all: $(program_NAME)
```

2nd `makefile.am` at the root directory is as shown below:

```
  SUBDIRS = src

  PRDSL_AutoProjectdocdir = ${prefix}/doc/PRDSL_AutoProject
  PRDSL_AutoProjectdoc_DATA = \
              README\
              COPYING\
              AUTHORS\
              ChangeLog\
              INSTALL\
              NEWS


     INTLTOOL_FILES = intltool-extract.in \
             intltool-merge.in \
             intltool-update.in

     EXTRA_DIST = $(PRDSL_AutoProjectdoc_DATA) \
             $(INTLTOOL_FILES)

     DISTCLEANFILES = intltool-extract \
             intltool-merge \
             intltool-update \
             po/.intltool-merge-cache


     # Remove doc directory on uninstall
     uninstall-local:
            -rm -r $(PRDSL_AutoProjectdocdir)
```

but I get the below errors and warnings while I was running `automake` command:

```
  src/Makefile.am:20: error: 'program_LIBRARIES' is used but 'programdir' is undefined
  src/Makefile.am:18: warning: 'CFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
  src/Makefile.am:18: use 'AM_CFLAGS' instead
  src/Makefile.am:43: error: AM_LDFLAGS must be set with '=' before using '+='
```

could any one review it and help me?

Comment: Didn't you get an answer about that error on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655278/what-is-the-difference-between-am-ldflags-and-ldflags)?

Comment: @EtanReisner unfortunately No, it doesn't solve my errors :(

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried to re-install automake and to upgrade it but the same error appears, I used this command to upgrade " sudo apt-get upgrade  automake" ?

Comment: @EtanReisner the automake version that I have is automake (GNU automake) 1.14.1
i think it is already updated, I'll write a feedback in the other question, but I am here asking for a reviewing of the whole makefile.am and for the the other error "  src/Makefile.am:20: error: 'program_LIBRARIES' is used but 'programdir' is undefined"

Comment: Ah, I think that "bug" was unrelated to automake itself. I didn't look closely enough. I've added an answer to the other question which should silence that error/warning assuming it is as simple as the message makes it sound. As to the other errors, the `CFLAGS` one is telling you to use `AM_CFLAGS`, yes. I believe you can avoid the `programdir` warning by not using an automake-style variable `program_LIBRARIES` for a non-automake purpose (manually adding `-l` arguments for external libraries).

Comment: @EtanReisner, thank you, but sorry I didn't get what you said about programdir and CFLAGS error, could you please give me an example or tell me how to adjust the code in order to avoid this error ?

Comment: I think you might be reinventing the wheel with many of your (genuinely good) questions. The autotools are *not* developer-friendly; they are [end]user-friendly. It's worth working through a [realistic](https://autotools.io/index.html) tutorial - even doing simple things *properly* requires a lot of knowledge upfront. This high barrier is the most frustrating thing about the autotools for developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `src/Makefile.am:43: error: AM_LDFLAGS must be set with '=' before using '+='` see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658342/258523) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655278/what-is-the-difference-between-am-ldflags-and-ldflags).

Yes, the following lines are telling you to use `AM_CFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS` because, as the error indicates, `CFLAGS` is a user-specified value and you should leave it alone.

```
src/Makefile.am:18: warning: 'CFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
src/Makefile.am:18: use 'AM_CFLAGS' instead
```

I believe, though I am far from certain, that the reason you are getting `src/Makefile.am:20: error: 'program_LIBRARIES' is used but 'programdir' is undefined` is because you are using a variable `program_LIBRARIES` that the autotools believe is a variable they should be using but that you are not using in that way and are instead using in the loop which sets the value for `AM_LDFLAGS`. As such, and assuming I am correct, if you rename that to not follow the autotool variable naming scheme I believe that error will go away.

Comment: i renamed the program_LIBRARIES to program_lib2 and didn't complain about this error anymore but it gives me a new error at executing make command from the terminal :(
but I'll mark your answer as correct one because it solve the above questions 
really thank, could I post the new error here if you want to help me ?

Comment: You can post it as a comment here but I'll probably just tell you to file a new question about it assuming it isn't immediately trivial.

Comment: it complains about the libraries, 
   make  all-recursive
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sara/NetBeansProjects    /PRDSL_AutoProject'
  Making all in src
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sara/NetBeansProjects /PRDSL_AutoProject/src'
  CCLD     PRDSL_AutoProject
  ../libtool: line 5986: cd: libprdependency: No such file or  directory
   libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of  `libprdependency'
make[2]: *** [PRDSL_AutoProject] Error 1

Comment: do you think maybe the problem cause of using dynamic and static libraries and including them in the same makefile variable ?

Comment: No, I think that's likely related to how you are manually trying to link things but I'm not sure. File a new question with the updated makefile.am and the new error message. Also you should really fix that `depend` target recipe from the comments I made about it in previous questions.

Comment: i think that you are right about depend, i guess that the problem will be in the depend command in the makefile. 
ok i will create a new question and share with you the link to it
and really thank you for your valuable comments and answers :)

Comment: No, the `depend` target likely doesn't have anything to do with that error. It is just wrong and I've mentioned the problems in comments before.

Comment: Actually, I get confused of that error, i tried all the suggested solution in the net but with no luck 
I am checking the depend target as you said before. 
btw here is the link of my new question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659549/makefile-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llibname-and-makedepend