# makefile error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibname and makedepend

Tags: c, linux, makefile, dependencies

I am trying to write my own makefile for small project, my project consists of src directory that contains main.c, file1.c, file2.c, header1.h, and finally header2.h these files use some library from non standard libraries directory that I have created and non standard header file, the libraries directory is located in usr/lib/pr__lib and the header directory is located in usr/include/lib
so I should create two makefile.am one will be located in src directory and the other one will be in root directory of the project the makefile.am of the src directory is as shown below:

```
program_NAME := myproject

AM_CPPFLAGS = \
   -DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""$(localedir)"\" \
   -DPACKAGE_SRC_DIR=\""$(srcdir)"\" \
   -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""$(pkgdatadir)"\"


bin_PROGRAMS = myproject_AutoProject

program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/bin/srr__bin

program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/lib/srr__lib

AM_CFLAGS = 

AM_CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

program_lib2 := \
      libsrr\
      libprdsl \
      libtwo \
      libhistogram \
      libhistogram_pic \
      libprlistofarrays \
      libprlistofarrays_pic \
      libprmalloc \
      libvreo 
AM_LDFLAGS = 

AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))

AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_lib2),-l$(library))

PRDSL_AutoProject_SOURCES = \
   main.c \
   file1.c \
   file2.c

depend :
    makedepend -$(CFLAGS) -$(PRDSL_AutoProject_SOURCES)

all: $(program_NAME)
```

the second makefile.am is as shown below:

```
SUBDIRS = src

myproject_AutoProjectdocdir = ${prefix}/doc/PRDSL_AutoProject
myproject_AutoProjectdoc_DATA = \
  README\
  COPYING\
  AUTHORS\
  ChangeLog\
  INSTALL\
  NEWS


INTLTOOL_FILES = intltool-extract.in \
  intltool-merge.in \
  intltool-update.in

EXTRA_DIST = $(myproject_AutoProjectdoc_DATA) \
   $(INTLTOOL_FILES)

DISTCLEANFILES = intltool-extract \
   intltool-merge \
 intltool-update \
 po/.intltool-merge-cache


# Remove doc directory on uninstall
uninstall-local:
  -rm -r $(PRDSL_AutoProjectdocdir)
```

but i have received the below error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibsrr
 /usr/bin/ld:.......
```

and the same for the rest of the libraries!
I guess that the problem in the depend command here, can anyone tell me how to use the depend command in order to create the dependency automatically and avoid human errors

Comment: Is that the exact error message? And you use `-lsrr` to link a `libsrr.so`/`libsrr.a` library.

Comment: some of the libraries is .a static and the other is .so dynamic 
yes this is the exact error now:
it gives the same error for all the libraries that I passed in the program_lib2 variable

Comment: `.a` vs. `.so` doesn't matter for `-l` generally. The name does. Drop the `lib` prefix from all of those names.

Comment: @EtanReisner many thanks :) you are makefile hero 
the error is solved but it complains about a new error which is related to depend 
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `myproject', needed by `all'.  Stop.

Comment: Your `depend` recipe is still not quite right but that's, again, likely not related. File a new question with the most up-to-date makefile and the new error message.

Answer (score 1):

can you make this change and let me know:

```
PathToMySource=`pwd` 
Program_INCLUDE_DIRS := /usr/bin/srr__bin

program_LIBRARY_DIRS := /usr/lib/srr__lib

AM_CFLAGS = 

AM_CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))

program_lib2 := \
      $(PathToMySource)/libsrr\
      $(PathToMySource)/libprdsl \
      $(PathToMySource)/libtwo \
      $(PathToMySource)/libhistogram \
      $(PathToMySource)/libhistogram_pic \
      $(PathToMySource)/libprlistofarrays \
      $(PathToMySource)/libprlistofarrays_pic \
      $(PathToMySource)/libprmalloc \
      $(PathToMySource)/libvreo 
AM_LDFLAGS = 

AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))

AM_LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_lib2),-l$(library))

PRDSL_AutoProject_SOURCES = \
   main.c \
   file1.c \
   file2.c

depend :
    makedepend -$(CFLAGS) -$(PRDSL_AutoProject_SOURCES)

all: $(program_NAME)
```

I am assuming that the folders are in the directory from where the make file is expected to run.

If they are not please add another variable and set the path. then use that variable in the place of PathToMySource.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @genesh I'll check this, but I tried the solution suggested in the comments above of removing the lib prefix from the libraries name and it worked with me, 
but gives me a new error that I guess it is related to target and makedepend make[2]: *** No rule to make target myproject', needed by all'. Stop

Comment: oh, so sorry, i made a mistake while copying it back. I have added that back.

Comment: @Sara, it is very hard to tell with the limited data that we can see by just looking at the make file content.